# Book recommendation for DFT/FFT?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, book-recommendation, fourier-transform

Which books deal with DFT/FFT?

Basically, I've already read about this subject in the book "Introduction to Algorithms" (CLRS), but I think it lacks of the mathematical aspects of the DFT, presenting DFT as a transform from *coefficient-form* to *point-form*, rather than presenting it as change of basis transformation.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://www.amazon.com/DFT-Owners-Discrete-Fourier-Transform/dp/0898713420) or [this](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-DFT/dp/097456074X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1492887393&sr=1-1&keywords=julius+fourier)

Comment: thanks @Bungo. By the way, I'm not limited for a whole book dealing with this subject. It could be a chapter in a book too.

Comment: Since the FFT has been around since the 60s there's really many books around by now. Is it to be used for some particular application?

Comment: we covered it as an application for evaluating polynomials in $\Theta(n\log n)$

Comment: Yes both evaluating, multiplying and dividing polynomials can be sped up by Fourier transforms since their coefficients convolve when they multiply.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at [Foundations of Signal Processing by Vetterli et al](http://fourierandwavelets.org/), or Mathematical Methods and Algorithms for Signal Processing by Moon and Stirling.

Most introductory signal processing texts will have some coverage, though not necessarily in the matrix view. You can also use [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).

As for FFT's, they're just an fast algorithm for computing DFT's; books like Discrete-Time Signal Processing by Oppenheim and Schafer have a chapter on this sort of thing (also Proakis' Digital Signal Processing, etc.).

One important part of the discrete fourier transform is that it diagonalizes circulant operators (i.e. circular convolution). And circular convolution is related to linear convolution, which is what a linear time invariant system does (convolves its impulse response with the input). Thus, the basis provided by the DFT is a special one (it's not an arbitrary orthonromal basis).

Comment: The basis functions complex exponentials also happen to be eigenfunctions to the differential operators which are super important in all applications which use differential equations for modelling.

Comment: Your statement about circulant operators is unclear. $W M W^*= \text{diag}(h)$ is diagonal iff $Mx = x \ast h$ where $h$ is the circular convolution.

Comment: thanks @mathreadler, I'll check that out!

Comment: @user1952009 - right. Cleared that up.

Comment: I meant $W$ is the DFT matrix (it is standard I think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix)

Comment: The Amazon link for the second book mentioned by @Batman is:
https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Methods-Algorithms-Signal-Processing/dp/0201361868/

Comment: The Amazon link for the first book mentioned by @Batman in their answer is:
https://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Signal-Processing-Martin-Vetterli-ebook/dp/B00LB6B9FM/

Comment: @evaristegd - the amazon link for the first book is to a kindle version; the ebook is free from the authors on their website (linked).